# vulnerable to Intent Redirection From Play Store

Tags: java

Intent Redirection
Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection.
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity->startActivityForResult
i have received this mail from google play and they removed my app from play store.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `android:exported="false"` in your activity and service tag that is present in the manifest file.

OR

You can check that the intent  Activity is from a trusted package
by using this line of code.

`if (getCallingActivity().getPackageName().equals(“known”))`